# installation of older kernel - as further option - no problem?

Tags: 12.10, grub2, kernel

Have not thought deeper in earlier sitin in terminal one year ago - and there I have removed Kernel 3.2.x

Now some newer Kernels have been installed like 3.5.x , 3.8.x , and 3.10.0-RC4

I want to know, if I can reinstall e.g. actual Kernel-Version of 3.2.26 ( is Ubuntu-Version as 3.2.50 available ? ).

I don't want downgrade, simply build-in 3.2.x as further option besides the newer ones.

Is this no problem ? - I would not risk an inconsistent system then ?

( yes - I should know this myself - but got slammed up by search results ... )

Here is 12.10

Answer (score 0):

You can install any kernel you want. There is no problem on using one or multiple Kernels at a time. But sometime you should consider the Kernel Mapping to your Ubuntu Version. For example following link lists out the mapping of different kernel to different version of OS:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/info/kernel-version-map.html

You can get a complete information of Kernel installing/removing from following link. It helped me a lot to install a new kernel in Ubuntu 12.04.2. Now I can chose any kernel 3.5.0 or 3.8.0 from grub menu.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds